# Unity build and Run game error: Error building Player: Extracting referenced dlls failed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Previously I created a game with Unity engine 4.5 and have now updated to Unity engine 5. The game runs well and is working perfectly, however, when I click "build and run" for Android, I get the following error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
    UnityEditor.PluginImporter+<GetImporters>c__AnonStoreyC.<>m__E (UnityEditor.PluginImporter imp) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/PluginImporterBindings.gen.cs:104)
    System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateWhereIterator>c__Iterator1D`1[UnityEditor.PluginImporter].MoveNext ()
    System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UnityEditor.PluginImporter].AddEnumerable (IEnumerable`1 enumerable) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:128)
    System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UnityEditor.PluginImporter]..ctor (IEnumerable`1 collection) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:65)
    System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[PluginImporter] (IEnumerable`1 source)
    UnityEditor.PluginImporter.GetImporters (System.String platformName) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/PluginImporterBindings.gen.cs:103)
    UnityEditor.PluginImporter.GetImporters (BuildTarget platform) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/PluginImporterBindings.gen.cs:111)
    UnityEditor.AndroidPluginImporterExtension.CheckFileCollisions (System.String buildTargetName)
    UnityEditorInternal.PluginsHelper.CheckFileCollisions (BuildTarget buildTarget) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Plugins/PluginsHelper.cs:25)
    UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check that you're on the right platform (in Build Settings).

If that's fine, try closing Unity, then manually delete the Library folder (in the project directory), and re-open (rebuild) the Unity project. I've noticed that works for me sometimes during these type of errors.

I hope that helps!

Comment: lets try deleting library folder and rebuild this project again. Hope so this works for me

Comment: @SyedMuhammadSalmanShah I'm glad, man. Would you mind selecting my response as the answer please? Thanks!